# How can i access a variable value from component1 in component2

Tags: angular

In **component 1** i have a function which returns a selected values from local storage using the code below, i wish to know is there any way to get the value of `this.array_no1` in **component2** so that i don't have to write this entire code again in `component2.component.ts` file. Please guide

```
ngOnInit() {
//this.document.body.innerHTML += this.myname;
 var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
  return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
});

var dataArray = keys.map(function(key) {
 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
});

for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
    var array_no = dataArray[i];
}
 this.array_no1 = dataArray;
console.log(this.array_no1);
  }
```

Comment: you can use NgRedux

Comment: you can use state management techniques `ngrx-store' for this

Comment: Services is what angular uses to share business logic between various components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your local storage code to shared service  and access it at as many as component you want.

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  public array_no1:any;

  constructor(){
  var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
     return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
  });

  var dataArray = keys.map(function(key) {
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  });

 for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
   var array_no = dataArray[i];
 }

 this.array_no1 = dataArray;
 console.log(this.array_no1);
 }
}
```

**app module**

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule,
      HttpModule],
 declarations: [AppComponent],
 providers: [SharedService],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}) export class AppModule { }
```

**your component**

```
import {SharedService} from 'path of service folder';
export class yourComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private router: Router,private sharedService:SharedService) {
}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.sharedService.array_no1 ;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try the same and let you know if i find any issues on the same.

Comment: Yeah sure, let me know if you have any issues